# Bash script to process all files in folder and save all output in different folder with same file names?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script to change size of svg images. Here is what I am trying

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
  rsvg-convert "$file" -w 160 -h 160 -f svg -o `echo $i | sed -e 's/svg$/new.svg/'`
done
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bash substitition directly (`${file%.svg}` will remvoe `.svg` from the end of `file` variable):

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p folder
for file in *
do
  rsvg-convert "$file" -w 160 -h 160 -f svg -o folder/${file%.svg}new.svg 
done
```

Comment: ^ for a solution with Bash substitution !

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer but I want same file names saved in different folder

Comment: @Sid It would be good to mention that in the question, I added that the answer

Comment: @krzyk apologies for not being clear. I tried to convey it in question heading but should have explained it in description also